# node-tar flatten directories

Tags: node.js, tar

I'm using [node-tar](https://github.com/npm/node-tar) to create a tar files. I'm looking to be able to flatten the directory structure, so that the TAR extracts to the cwd folder.

For instance, if I'm packing...

```
/some/dir/foo.jpg
/some/other/dir/bar/jpg
```

I'd like it to be packed, and unpack as...

```
foo.jpg
bar.jpg
```

I realise that there is a way of doing this at the unpack stage (`--strip-components`), but that bit is out of my control and I need to replicate a legacy system.

In another library ([tar-fs](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-fs)) I used, I did the following...

```
// Create TAR stream
tar.pack('/', {
    entries: ['/some/dir/foo.jpg', '/some/other/dir/bar.jpg'],
    map    : function (header) {
        header.name = path.basename(header.name);
        return header
    }
});
```

But I can't use this one, as it is based on ustar, and limited to 8GB files.

Thanks in advance